# Creating an NSIS installer for ConfigMgr that will cause ConfigMgr client to initiate a restart

Tags: windows-7, installation, sccm, automated-install, sccm-2012

I have been using NSIS to create install packages for applications developed by our in-house development staff for several years, and we have recently switched from an alternative product to ConfigMgr for software distribution. I would like to harness ConfigMgr's built-in ability to handle computer restarts, but I have not been able to find a way to do this. If I use ConfigMgr to distribute an MSI or MSU that requires a restart, the ConfigMgr client will prompt the user to restart after x minutes (based on the global Client Settings that we have pre-configured), but when using an EXE created with NSIS, it does not. Does anyone know what I would need to add to the NSIS package to make ConfigMgr aware that a restart is required?

Edit: To clarify the question, I am attempting to create an NSIS installer that I can add to ConfigMgr as a package, but I need the NSIS installer to have whatever is necessary for ConfigMgr to recognise that a restart is required. Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Chck

Answer (score 0):

In the application you setup in ConfigMgr you can specify a return code in the deployment type, in there you can say how that code will be handled by ConfigMgr, so you just need to specify a soft restart return code and handle that in ConfigMgr, or use the default, which I cannot remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the program for the package you are distributing, use the "After Running" pull down menu to select "Configuration Manager restarts computer. ConfigMgr will use the exit code of your installer (usually 0 or 3010) as the signal that the install has completed. Since NSIS is a scripted installer, you can have it use either or both to say that the package has finished its operations, restart now. Make sure you set an appropriate countdown so that the user has a chance to exit all their open programs, if needed.